# Replacement of MediaPlayerLauncher in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

What is the replacement of the [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004(v=vs.105).aspx) in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal apps?

Launching the URI opens the browser:

```
var options = new LauncherOptions();
options.ContentType = "video/mp4";
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri.Uri, options);
```

Or crashes when setting the ContentType (as shown above).

What's the solution (except to implement an own page with a player)?

Comment: If the `uri.Uri` locations is on the `LocalStorage` you may want to try `LaunchFileAsync` instead of `LaunchUriAsync`, this should allow you to launch the video using an external player. I've not tested it though, it's just a random guess since nobody replied

Comment: It's a HTTP uri, so I think this will not work...

Comment: I have NotImplementedException on string options.ContentType = "video/mp4"; for Windows Phone device. I think this is bug

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for MediaPlayerLauncher in WP 8.1 RT

The only solution is using MediaElement to play video in app.